# how to iterate through request for multiple times?

Tags: javascript, postman

I trying to iterate a delivery request for 3 times, but my code loops more than that, can someone please tell me why?

I tried so many examples from internet all of goes loop or crash in memory

I don't have any cvs file or anything that I'm trying to get the data from all set in body with some pre-request script that auto generate the values to the body.

[call I want to repeat and I have 2 request in collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXGTv.png)

In first token request I wrote couple of variables

```
pm.environment.set("repeat", 0);
pm.environment.set("count", 3);
```

[token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ikKe.png)

and in second request I'm trying to iterate the call

```
while(pm.environment.get('count') >= pm.environment.get('repeat')){
    postman.setNextRequest('delivery');
    console.log("iteration " +pm.environment.get('repeat'))
    pm.environment.get('repeat')+1;
}
```

[delivery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brFY9.png)

Comment: Not familiar with postman, but does `pm.environment.get('repeat')+1;` actually increase the value of variable? Because it seems like it would get the value, then increase the value by 1, but not set that value to anything, and not update the original variable.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, classic off by one error, there are four iterations between 0 and 3 if you do `>=`.
Try `>`:

```js
for(let i = pm.environment.get('count'); i > 0; i--){
  ...
}
```

Comment: call is going into infinite loop, no stop until I stop the thread

Comment: can you post the loop declaration?

Comment: `while(pm.environment.get('count') > pm.environment.get('repeat')) {
    postman.setNextRequest('delivery');
    console.log("this is iteration " ,pm.environment.get('repeat'))
    pm.environment.get('repeat')++;
}`

Comment: just use the `for` loop, make sure that `pm.environment.get('count')` gets you the number of retries

Comment: changes to for loop and I edited script, 
`for(let i = pm.environment.get('count'); i > 0; i--) {
    console.log(i)
    postman.setNextRequest('delivery');
}`
It just loop and print 3,2,1 but call run only one time

Comment: Sounds like your `postman.setNextRequest('delivery');` is not working as you think it does. Have you looked at the documentation?